# How to resolve cors origin exception

Tags: node.js, express, cors

We deployed our nodejs app to aws ,but it is giving this error while accessing any api,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://vkluy41ib9.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/auth/login' from origin 'https://cmc-app.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Now the issue if our node app is  hosted on localhost its working fine but deploying on live server its throwing error

this is our code :

```
app.options(cors());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //Enabling CORS
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-client-key, x-client-token, x-client-secret, Authorization"
  );
  next();
})
```

Comment: Can you see the headers in the inspector?

Comment: It might be a setting to find at the aws console level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `cors()` then you need to write:

```
app.options("*", cors());
```

otherwise it will not be registered correctly. Using this method, the handler returned from `cors()` will be used on all `OPTIONS`-requests.

The second part where you do `app.use` is not necessary, because it does nearly the same as the method before.

To get the result you wanted with the second part, you could write:

```
app.options("*", cors({
  methods: ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "POST", "PUT"],
  allowedHeaders: ["origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "x-client-key", "x-client-token", "x-client-secret", "Authorization"]
}));
```

All configuration options for cors are listed here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options